# Prevent iframe breakout HTML 5 / JS

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am currently working on a Chrome Extension that mimics the behaviour and functionality of Firefox's Responsive Design View.

Everything is almost finished, and generally working well. However, I ran into a problem that I'd like to circumvent if possible. I have used an `iframe` that users can manipulate in terms of size, etc., but certain sites (including StackOverflow) do not allow themselves to be embedded in Frames (warning about security).

Does anyone have a solution to prevent this behaviour? I do not want to use server-side code for this. Removing the iframe in favour of another method is also fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior cannot be overridden, quite deliberately. If a site declares that it doesn't want to allow itself to be embedded in frames, there is precisely nothing you can do about it.