# IFrame breakout

Tags: javascript, css, iframe

Trying to work out how to prevent iframe break out of the following page.

http://www.virginaustralia.com/au/en/

The page loads fine in the iframe, but when I go to search for a flight, the break out occurs due to anti-iframe javascript I assume. I would like for this flight search to remain within the iframe.

My Iframe is pretty straight forward:
`<iframe id= "vaus" name="vaus" align="top" src="http://www.virginaustralia.com/au/en/" style="-webkit-transform:scale(0.75);"></iframe>`

I've tried various Javascript suggestions on here and nwdisable, nwfaketop, allow- fixes, but nothing has worked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Note the purpose is not for commercial purposes.

Thanks

Comment: This is probably the [generic answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14734342/351836) to this kind of question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent iframe breakout HTML 5 / JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14734296/prevent-iframe-breakout-html-5-js)

Answer (score 0):

If the website has an iframe breakout, there's nothing you can do.